# Show popul only on a first visit

Tags: jquery, popup

I have this code on my website, which displays a popup window with a link, but I'd like to show it only for first-time visitors only. Can someone help me please? I'll be very thankful!

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ABT_closeButton = document.getElementById('ABT_close_button');
    var ABT_float_ads_main_Wrap = document.getElementById('ABT_float_ads_main_Wrap');

    myVar = setTimeout(function() {
        ABT_float_ads_main_Wrap.style.display = 'block';
    }, 1000);

    ABT_closeButton.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('ABT_float_ads_main_Wrap').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

— Berenica

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve it would be storing user navigation event in cookies. I mean, once user navigates to this page, you just store some value in cookies. You also need to check if value is already stored, and if it’s true, do not display the popup. You can also use localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is store a flag in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to reflect that the user has already seen the popup.

```
window.onload = function() {
    function showPopup() {
        var ABT_closeButton;
        var ABT_float_ads_main_Wrap;

        if (localStorage.getItem('popup')) {
             return;
        }

        ABT_closeButton = document.getElementById('ABT_close_button');
 = document.getElementById('ABT_float_ads_main_Wrap');
        ABT_float_ads_main_Wrap = document.getElementById('ABT_float_ads_main_Wrap');

        ABT_float_ads_main_Wrap.style.display = 'block';
        ABT_closeButton.onclick = function() {
            ABT_float_ads_main_Wrap.style.display = 'none';
        }

        localStorage.setItem('popup', 'shown');
    }

    myVar = setTimeout(showPopup, 1000);
}
```